# how to show the probability of no occurrences of a single digit in a fractional expansion is a simple formula?

Tags: probability

Say I have a binary string of length 1.  What is the probability I never see a 0? My binary string can only be a 0 or 1. So obviously the probability I never see a 0 is 1/2. If instead I have a base of 3 and length of 1 then what is the probability I never see a 0? Well my string could be a 0,1, or 2.  So this would be 2/3 probability.  If I increase the length of my string to 2 then I could have 00,01,02,10,11,12,20,21,22.  Now the probability I never see a 0 becomes 4/9.

In general the probability is a simple formula : $(base-1)^n / base^n$.  But how do I prove this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are essentially there.  There are $base - 1$ non-zero digits, so there are $(base-1)^n$ strings of length $n$ that do not include zero.  There are $base^n$ total strings, so the ratio is as you stated.

Comment: But is that a proof?

Comment: It depends on your audience.  I believe in most contexts it would be accepted.  You are counting the favorable events and the total events, then taking the ratio.

Comment: So there is no induction involved?

Comment: No, this direct computation suffices.  I think it could be formulated with induction, but that would be much more complicated.